# interpolation of Fourier decoupling

Tags: fourier-analysis, interpolation

I am listening to the class of Tao at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2020/04/13/247b-notes-2-decoupling-theory/. And I have trouble in the interpolation property of decoupling constant in exercise 10.

(iv) (Interpolation) Suppose that $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1-\theta}{p_{0}}+\frac{\theta}{p_{1}}$ for some $1 \leq p_{0} \leq p \leq p_{1} \leq \infty$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 1,$ and suppose also that $\mathcal{U}=\left\{U_{1}, \ldots, U_{n}\right\}$ is a non-empty collection of open non-empty subsets of $\mathbf{R}^{d}$ for which one has the projection bounds
$$
\left\|P_{U_{j}} f\right\|_{L^{p_{i}}\left(\mathbf{R}^{d}\right)} \lesssim_{p_{i}, d}\|f\|_{L^{p_{i}}\left(\mathbf{R}^{d}\right)}
$$
for all $f \in \mathcal{S}\left(\mathbf{R}^{d}\right), i=0,1,$ and $j=1, \ldots, n,$ where the Fourier multiplier $P_{U_{i}}$ is defined bv$$\widehat{P_{U_{j}} f}(\xi)=1_{U_{j}}(\xi) \hat{f}(\xi)$$
Show that
$$
\operatorname{Dec}_{p}(\mathcal{U}) \lesssim_{p_{0}, p_{1}, d, \theta} \operatorname{Dec}_{p_{0}}(\mathcal{U})^{1-\theta} \operatorname{Dec}_{p_{1}}(\mathcal{U})^{\theta}
$$

Any ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the operator $T:\ell^2(L^p(\mathbb{R}^d))\to L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ given by
$$
T(\{f_j\}) := \sum_j P_{U_j}f_j.
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\lVert T(\{f_j\})\rVert_{p_i} &\le Dec_{p_i}(\mathcal{U})\Big(\sum_j\lVert P_{U_j}f_j\rVert_{p_i}^2\Big)^\frac{1}{2} \\\\
&\lesssim_{p_i,d}Dec_{p_i}(\mathcal{U})\Big(\sum_j\lVert f_j\rVert_{p_i}^2\Big)^\frac{1}{2},
\end{align}
$$
where we used the hypothesis on $P_{U_j}$. Since $T$ is $L^{p_i}$-bounded, then by Riesz-Thorin theorem we get
$$
\lVert T(\{f_j\})\rVert_{p_i} \lesssim_{p,d}Dec_{p_0}(\mathcal{U})^{1-\theta}Dec_{p_1}(\mathcal{U})^\theta\Big(\sum_j\lVert f_j\rVert_{p_i}^2\Big)^\frac{1}{2},
$$
and the exercise follows after taking $f_j$ with Fourier support in $U_j$.